# Can we have two popup windows in single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter

```js
 function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myDIV1").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "inline";
 }

 function myFunction1() {
   document.getElementById("myDIV1").style.display = "inline";
   document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
 }
```

```css
#myDIV {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 1212px;
  height: 620px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 600;
}
#myDIV1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 1212px;
  height: 620px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 600;
}
#shadow {
  background: rgba(202, 188, 160, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 47px;
  left: 213px;
  width: 801px;
  height: 570px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 5px 27px 5px rgba(71, 68, 71, 0.57);
  -moz-box-shadow: 9px 5px 27px 5px rgba(71, 68, 71, 0.57);
  box-shadow: 9px 5px 27px 5px rgba(71, 68, 71, 0.57);
}
.privacy-stat {
  background: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  width: 759px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  left: 213px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #666666;
  border-left-color: #666666;
  border-top-color: #666666;
  border-right-color: #666666;
}
#title-bar {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  width: 799px;
  height: 27px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 213px;
  top: 47px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left-color: #666666;
  border-top-color: #666666;
  border-right-color: #666666;
  z-index: 600;
}
#close {
  position: fixed;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  position: relative;
  left: 769px;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
 <a onClick="myFunction()" href="#" class="button"><span>ADD EMPLOYEE</span></a>
<a onclick="myFunction1()" href="#" class="button"><span>EDIT</span></a>


<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="shadow">
    <div class="privacy-stat">
      <div id="title-bar">
        <div id="close">
          <a href="employee/list"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/cancel.svg" height="30" width="30"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sky-tabs sky-tabs-pos-top-left sky-tabs-response-to-icons">
        <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" checked="" id="sky-tab1" class="sky-tab-content-1">
        <label for="sky-tab1"><span><span>Contact</span></span>
        </label>

        <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" id="sky-tab2" class="sky-tab-content-2">
       
        <ul>
          <li class="sky-tab-content-1">
            <div class="typography">

              style="word-spacing: 1px;font-size:12px;">
              <fieldset>


                <legend>
                  <p>GENERAL</p>
                </legend>


                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label>Employee id:</label>

                  <input type="text" id="" name="id" value="<?php echo set_value('id'); ?>">
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label>First name:</label>

                  <input type="text" id="" name="emp_first_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="enter a valid name only characters are allowed" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_first_name'); ?>">

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label for="inputError">Last name:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="" name="emp_last_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="enter a valid name only characters are allowed" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_last_name'); ?>">
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Email id</label>
                  <input type="text" id="" name="emp_email_id" pattern="^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" title="enter a valid email for example sample@sample.com" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_email_id'); ?>">
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label for="inputError">Emergency contact</label>
                  <input type="text" name="emp_emergency_contact" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="enter valid contact. it must contain 10 digits" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_emergency_contact'); ?>">

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label>Category:</label>
                  <?php echo form_dropdown( 'category', $options_designation, set_value( 'category'), 'class="span2"'); ?>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div id="designation">
                  <?php if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'designation');?>
                  <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/designation" class="button"><span>Add</span></a>

                </div>

                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">




                  <label>Date of hire</label>

                  <input type="date" name="emp_date_of_hire" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_date_of_hire'); ?>">

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label>Date of termination</label>

                  <input type="date" name="emp_date_of_termination" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_date_of_termination'); ?>">

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <label>Date of rehire</label>
                  <input type="date" name="emp_date_of_rehire" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_date_of_rehire'); ?>">
                </div>
                </br>

                <div class="inputwrap">


                  <label>Referenece number</label>

                  <input type="text" name="emp_reference_num" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="enter valid contact. it must contain 10 digits" value="<?php echo set_value('emp_reference_num'); ?>">


                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="inputwrap">


                  <label>System name</label>

                  <input type="text" name="system_name" value="<?=$system_name ?>">


                </div>
                </br>



                <div class="inputwrap">
                  <button id="btn" type="submit">NOTES</button>
                  <button id="btn" type="submit">SAVE</button>
                  <button id="btn" type="reset">CANCEL</button>
                </div>

              </fieldset>
              <?php echo form_close(); ?>

              </fieldset>
              </FONT>

            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--For edit-->
  <div id="myDIV1">
    <div id="shadow">
      <div class="privacy-stat">
        <div id="title-bar">
          <div id="close">
            <a href="employee/list"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/cancel.svg" height="30" width="30"/></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sky-tabs sky-tabs-pos-top-left sky-tabs-response-to-icons">
          <input type="radio" name="sky-tabs" checked="" id="sky-tab1" class="sky-tab-content-1">
          <label for="sky-tab1"><span><span>Contact</span></span>
          </label>



          <ul>
            <li class="sky-tab-content-1">
              <div class="typography">
<p>This my edit page<p>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Edit end-->
```

I am using codeigniter.In my view page I have two  element add and edit. For popup like window I have used  element. For single buttons action I can get my results But when I have two buttons It do not work. Can someone solve this? Please help me code.
I have this script.Here I change the div elements display attribute.This div element appears only when the button is clicked.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "inline";
}
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV1").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>
```

This is my CSS. Here I have `myDiv` and `myDiv1` for each popup window.

```
#myDIV {


    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 1212px;
    height: 620px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 600;

}
#myDIV1 {


    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 1212px;
    height: 620px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 600;

}
```

My view page.Here I have two button action add and edit. Here I called my script.

```
<div id="add">

        <a onClick="myFunction()" href="#" class="button"><span>ADD EMPLOYEE</span></a>
        <a onclick="myFunction1()" href="#" class="button"><span>EDIT</span></a>
</div>
```

This is my popup window content.

```
  <div id="myDIV">
....
    </div>

    <div id="myDIV1">
   .....
    </div>
```

When adding another button action It also disturbs the first popup windows result.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is when you click the `ADD EMPLOYEE` button again, it does not hide the `EDIT` pop and does not show the `myDIV` popup.

To solve this, what you have to do is, every time one of the buttons is clicked, first hide the existing popup using `style.display = 'none'`. Then show the relevant popup.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "inline";
}

function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDIV1").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 1212px;
  height: 620px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 600;
}
#myDIV1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 1212px;
  height: 620px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myDIV">
  MY DIV
</div>

<div id="myDIV1">
  MY DIV 1
</div>

<div id="add">

  <a onClick="myFunction()" href="#" class="button"><span>ADD EMPLOYEE</span></a>
  <a onclick="myFunction1()" href="#" class="button"><span>EDIT</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Still there is problem with the first popup

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _problem_? What is the issue you are running into?

Comment: I need to close my first popup window and then onen next. For closing I have a <a> element. In my code I could not see the second popup window

Comment: The code in my answer works like this... 1) When you click `ADD EMPLOYEE` the `myDIV` popup will open. 2) When you click `EDIT` the `myDIV` will be closed and `myDIV1` will be opened. 3) When you click `ADD EMPLOYEE` again, `myDIV1` will be closed and the `myDIV` will be opened. Isn's this the behavior you expect?

Comment: That's fine. In my code I could not get the second popup.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `<a herf="javascript:void(0);"></a>` to anchor tag then it will work. 
find **[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNwXRp)**

```
<div id="add">
        <a href="javacsript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" class="button"><span>ADD EMPLOYEE</span></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction1()" class="button"><span>EDIT</span></a>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">myDIV</div>
<div id="myDIV1">myDIV1</div>
```

Comment: I have a  <a> element to close myDiv and click edit.  I could not see the edit popup.

Comment: I was trying to solve this before you post demo. I think you posted demo little later. Now I can see pop up in you demo. So add <a herf="javascript:void(0);"></a> in you anchor tag then It will work fine.

Comment: But I could not get in my code? I have added <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

Comment: are you sure. you don't want to use jquery? I can do this more comfortably in jquey than javascript.

Comment: finally I find the bug. Actually error was in you html <div> closing. You didn't close #myDIV so #myDIV1 was also coming in #myDIV. now it is solved find working fiddle demo with jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/2bxvs0sa/

Comment: I could get two popup window. But now little trouble.Content in First popup is not displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87632/discussion-between-locateganesh-and-anu).